# What is 'in-plane' and 'out-of-plane' magnetization in anisotropic magnets?

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, material-science

Can someone explain what 'in-plane' and 'out-of-plane' magnetization refers to in anisotropic magnets?

Comment: That depends on the context, although the most common situation is where the magnet has a high aspect ratio that makes it relatively planar in shape.

Answer (score 1):

Most magnetic materials in reality have some amount of magneto-crystalline anisotropy. This arises from spin-orbit coupling. This magneto-crystalline anisotropy dictates the 'easy', 'intermediate' and 'hard' axes in a magnet - For example, if your material has an 'easy' axis in-plane, this means that the lowest energy state is for a configuration in which the spins (or magnetic moments) on the atoms are pointing in-plane.